# Partial refresh in WordPress live preview

Tags: php, customization, jquery, theme-customizer

I have used the **number input controller** for the WordPress customization section.

By entering the new number, the whole page is refreshed in the live preview, and the reason for this is because of the `'transport' => 'refresh'` **argument**. By changing this argument to '`transport' => 'postMessage'`, it will no longer be refreshed by entering the page number.

**But a new problem arises**; And that is that I no longer see the newly entered number in the live preview. I have to first click on the publish button and then refresh the whole page to display the entered number.

**By searching on the internet**, I realized that I need to introduce a **new object** in the form of `$wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial` for partial refresh, so that I can refresh only the desired part instead of refreshing the whole page.

I have set the `'render_callback'` argument to `'__return_false'` to maybe achieve my goal, but when I enter a new number, after a few seconds pause, the full page is refreshed again and the new number is shown in the live preview.

**My main question:**

How can I create a **jQuery** function and pass it to the `'render_callback'` argument so that only that part is refreshed when the new number is entered? or any other method that can lead me to this goal.

The codes I put in the `functions.php` file:

```
function controller_theme_Number ($wp_customize){

    // Create section
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'controlID_for_section',
    array(
    'title'              => __( 'Numerical input controller', 'theme_slug' ),
    'priority'           => 10, 
    ));


   // Create setting
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'controlID_for_setting', 
    array(
    'default'              => '5',
    'type'                 => 'theme_mod', // or option
    'transport'            => 'postMessage', // or refresh 
    ));


    // Create control
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control(
    $wp_customize, 
   'controlID_for_control',
    array(
    'label'         => __('Number controller','theme_slug' ),
    'description'   => esc_html__( 'Enter the number you want' ),
    'priority'      => 10,
    'type'          => 'number',
    'input_attrs'   => array(
      'class'       => 'my-custom-class',  // Create a class for the controller
    ),
    'section'       => 'controlID_for_section',
    'settings'      => 'controlID_for_setting',
    )));
    
    
    
   // Create partial
   $wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial( 'controlID_for_setting',
   array(
      'selector' => '.my-custom-class',    // Select the desired class
      'container_inclusive' => false,
      'render_callback' => '__return_false',
      'fallback_refresh' => true
  ));
    
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'controller_theme_Number' );
```

**How to display the output of the controller on the target page:**

```
<?php echo get_theme_mod('controlID_for_setting'); ?>
```